# String multi linea con format en python, como declararlo de la manera mas prolija posible?

Tags: python, json, string, formato

Tengo una url la cual debo pasarle distintos id por parametros:

```
ids = ['MOV42425', 'MOV28393', 'MOV99345', etc]
for identificador in ids:
    try:
        url = requests.get(f'https://contentapi-ar.cdn.telefonica.com/29/default/es-AR/content/**{identificador}**/children?ca_deviceTypes=null%7C401&fields=pid,title,seasonNumber,childrenCount,commercializationType,availableUntil&includeRelations=Episode,Media&includeAttributes=ca_devicetypes_qualities&contentPid=**{identificador}**&cachetime=202103041800')
    except:
          print(f'Error de conexión con url id {identificador}')
```

Quisiera que ocupe varias lineas porque queda bastante ilegible a lo largo, como es posible hacerlo teniendo el string format dentro?
Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Python permite separar una cadena literal en varios "trozos" y si los pones uno tras otro, los concatenará en uno solo (los espacios entre los trozos son irrelevantes).

Por ejemplo:

```
texto = "Hola, "     "que tal"

# Equivale a
texto = "Hola, que tal"
```

Y si está entre paréntesis, puedes separarlo en varias líneas:

```
texto = ("Hola, "
         "que tal")
```

Observa que no pongo ninguna coma entre las cadenas (pues entonces sería una tupla). Podrías poner un `+` para hacer más explícita la concatenación, pero aún sin el `+` python las concatenará por ser cadenas literales.

Este truco también funciona para las f-strings, por lo que aplicando esto a tu caso podría quedar así:

```
ids = ['MOV42425', 'MOV28393', 'MOV99345', etc]
for identificador in ids:
    try:
        url = requests.get(f'https://contentapi-ar.cdn.telefonica.com/29/default' 
                           f'/es-AR/content/**{identificador}**/children?'
                           f'ca_deviceTypes=null%7C401&fields=pid,title,'
                           f'seasonNumber,childrenCount,commercializationType,'
                           f'availableUntil&includeRelations=Episode,Media'
                           f'&includeAttributes=ca_devicetypes_qualities&'
                           f'contentPid=**{identificador}**&'
                           f'cachetime=202103041800')
    except:
          print(f'Error de conexión con url id {identificador}')
```

**Nota** estrictamente la `f` de f-string sólo sería necesaria en los trozos que contengan una `"{variable}"`, pero por uniformidad y legibilidad la he puesto en todos los trozos,

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!